# Nested fixed effects in the lme4 package

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model, nested-models

I have browsed the internet for an answer to my question but have failed in my attempts. My experimental design includes nested fixed effects and I do not know how to specify this in my model in the lme4 package or if it is even possible.

For my experiment I have collected seeds from Festuca rubra growing on Iceland. Across Iceland a band of vulcanic activity streaches, that heats the soil making these areas at lot warmer than the rest of the island. Seeds were collected from 5 heated localities and 5 non-heated, making it 10 different populations, 5 heated and 5 non-heated. However, the localities are very different making it hard to argue that the populations are replicates. I want to know if the if the variation is larger between populations growing on the same soil-type or between populations growing on different soil-types in regards to survival, biomass productions etc.

Below is a sketch of my experimental design

[image]

My random effect is block nested in treatment 1, my fixed effects are treatment 1 and population nested within treatment 2, is it possible to express this in a model?

(survival~treatment1+?treatment2/population?+(1|treatment2/block)

Answer (score 2):

Your study design is not at all clear - can you provide more details to help potential responders understand what is really going on?

What is clear is that you selected 5 locations where the soil is heated and 5 locations where the soil is non-heated. But what exactly are you measuring at each location, how and how often? For example, if you gather seeds of Festuca rubra at each location, how many seeds are you gathering per location and what are you measuring for these seeds? In particular, are you aggregating the thing(s) you are measuring across seeds and reporting a single aggregated value per location?

What is the blocking factor shown into your diagram and how does it come into play into your study? Is the blocking factor something like year? What is the difference between the blocking factors a through d and the blocking factors e through h?

You also don't mention much about the snow treatment - was snow physically removed at all locations with heated soil as a part of your study or did it simply melt by itself? If snow melts by itself resulting in "snow removal", the heated location and the removed snow are equivalent - you can't have a heated location without having melted snow. In that case, I can't see how your Treatment 1 and Treatment 2 would not refer to the exact same thing?

Comment: Sorry, I will develop it further. The seeds were collected and brought from Iceland to Sweden for a common garden experiment. In each block (a-h), 20 seeds were planted in individual pots from each of the 10 populations. This was done in spring. During the winter, snow was removed from four of the blocks (a-d), and the following spring we measured survival. Furthermore, over the summer we also recorded phenology and at the end of the study we measured above ground biomass.
I hope this clearifies it.